# disable a menu item in Angular uib-dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs

In my angular template I'm creating a dropdown menu using **angular-ui**, I need to disable some of the list items based on a property of the "company" object defined in the ng-repeat.

I already tried the **disabled** tag or the **ng-disabled** directive but without success. How can i achieve that?

My current code:

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="dropdown-open">
    <button id="companyDropDown" type="button" class="btn btn-default"
     uib-dropdown-toggle>
         {{companyDescr}}<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu"
     aria-labelledby="companyDropDown">
        <li role="menuItem" ng-repeat="company in companyContracts">
            <a ng-click="selectContract(company)">{{company.address}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `disabled` class from Bootstrap with ng-class directive from Angular.

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="companyDropDown">
    <li  ng-class="{'disabled': company.disabled }" role="menuItem" ng-repeat="company in companyContracts">
        <a ng-click="selectContract(company)">{{company.address}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

According to Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-disabled), the disabled class must be applied to the `<li>` element.

Comment: can you add live demo

Comment: Thank you! It was so easy...
I'm still new to the environment :P

Comment: Yeah sometimes simpler solutions just work out of the box, that's when I love Angular ^^